# Returning string array to other class(include inheritance) and print

Tags: java, arrays, return-value

I have a problem with return an array to other class or inheritance child class in java.

**class A**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class A {
  String [] month = new String[4];  
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

 public String[] Select()
  {
        System.out.println("choose");   

        int pick=sc.nextInt();
        switch(pick)
     {
        case 1:
           month[0]="January";          
          break;
        case 2:
            month[0]="February";                
        break;
    case 3:
        month[0]="March";           
        break;
    case 4:             
        month[0]="April";   
        break;

    }
    return month;
}
```

}

**class C**

```
    public class C extends A{

     public void child_class() 
   {
        System.out.println(month[0]);
   }        

}
```

**class B**

```
public class B {

    A  select = new A ();
    public void normal_class()
    {       
        System.out.println(select.month[0]);
    }
 }
```

**Main Class**
public class main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        A sun = new A();
        B moon = new B();
        C star = new C();

        System.out.println(sun.month[0]);           
        moon.normal_class(); //
        star.child_class();
        }
```

}

**result**

```
null
null
null
```

I would like to return an array's result to class or child class.
If I choose case 1 in A class, I want to get the result "January" from the classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct and complete the classes in the question, copy them as in the editor and make sure they look correct using the preview.
I don't get where the `test` in `print(test.arr[0]);` in class B comes from.
However you are printing objects that you have not initialized. That's why you see null.

When you create A with `A sun = new A();` and then you print it `print(sun.arr[0]);` you have never run test or assigned a value to arr for example.

After editing the original classes.

`System.out.println(sun.month[0]);` is accessing `month` in class `A` but since you didn't call `Select` method (which should start with lowercase) you will never populate the array month with data.

Try this:

```
public class A {
  String [] month = new String[4];  

 public String[] select(int pick)
  {
        switch(pick)
     {
        case 1:
           month[0]="January";          
          break;
        case 2:
            month[0]="February";                
        break;
    case 3:
        month[0]="March";           
        break;
    case 4:             
        month[0]="April";   
        break;

    }
    return month;
}
```

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    A sun = new A();
    B moon = new B();
    C star = new C();

    sun.select(1);
    System.out.println(sun.month[0]); //printing January
    moon.normal_class(); //you are not printing anything here
    star.child_class(); //you are not printing anything here
    }
```

Comment: If I use switch that I get the number(the pick) from the scanner, How can I change my code?

Comment: I simplified the example, in the main method add the scanner and once you have the number, send it as a parameter to the select method.

Comment: @Mjchoi glad to help, please tag my answer as correct ;-)